# Integrate: $\int\ln(2x+1) \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int\ln(2x+1) \, dx$$

I setting up this problem and I am finding it hard to understand why $dv= 1$.

When using this formula 
$$\int u\ dv=uv-\int v\ du$$

And using these Guidelines for Selecting $u$ and $dv$:

“L-I-A-T-E” Choose $u$ to be the function that comes first in this list:

L: Logrithmic Function

I: Inverse Trig Function

A: Algebraic Function

T: Trig Function

E: Exponential Function

Comment: Because your function can be written as $1*ln(2x+1)$ and so the $1$ will have to be chosen as your $dv$ which then becomes an $x$ as part of the term after the integral sign

Comment: @imranfat What is one considered in the LIATE table?

Comment: Do you *have to* use integration by parts? If not, it might be easier to use the substitution $y = 2x + 1$.

Comment: To be honest, I am not so familiar with the LIATE acronym. Maybe others on this site are. MY experience is that if you want to try integration by parts (IBP) and the function does not consist of a product of 2 functions (like in your case), then you "write" it as a product of $1*f(x)$ but then you don't have any choice as to what the $dv$ would be.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich. I would sub away $2x+1$ and then after that I would sub away the entire $ln$. It really becomes the anti derivative of $te^t$ which is very standard. But for the sake of practice, and that is what Sunny does, IBP is a worthy approach.

Comment: Sunny. For the sake of some more practice of problems that falls exactly in the same category as yours, you can try to find the anti derivative of $arcsinx$, $arccosx$, and $arctanx$ in a similar fashion. You write $1$ in front of all of them and then choose $1=dv$. Good luck

Comment: @Sunny I really agree with imranfat's previous comment. The arctrig functions make great practice integrals using this idea.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\int\underbrace{\ln(2x+1)}_\text{This is $u$.} \, dx & = \int u\,dx = ux - \int x\,du \\[10pt]
& = x\ln(2x+1) - \int x\cdot \frac{2}{2x+1} \,dx \quad\text{etc.} \\[10pt]
& = x\ln(2x+1) - \int \left( 1 - \frac 1 {2x+1} \right) \,dx \qquad \text{etc.}
\end{align}

Comment: Isn't the derivative of 2x+1 = 2? How did you get 2x on the second line?

Comment: @Sunny The extra $x$ comes from the $v$ part of  $v\,du$

Comment: Haste makes waste.  I was right the first time. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

This is a really tricky problem to see for the first time, but it does fit with the guidelines you give.

The first choice if possible for $u$ is the logarithmic function. However, we also need another function in order to use integration by parts. What are we to do? Well, although it doesn't look like much, we can realize that $\ln(2x+1)=1\cdot\ln(2x+1)$, and now suddenly we have two functions and can try integration by parts. Turns out it works nicely enough too

$$\begin{align}\int\ln(2x+1)\,dx&=\int1\cdot\ln(2x+1)\,dx=x\ln(2x+1)-\int x\cdot\frac{2}{2x+1}\,dx
\end{align}$$
and it's not too hard to finish off the integral from here.

Comment: You just provided the entire answer...(sigh)

Comment: @imranfat I didn't think that the OP had a problem with getting the answer, just understanding how to set up the problem, but it's easy enough for me to get rid of the last few steps

Comment: Yeah, the set up was her issue I think. I should be straight forward now

Comment: at this point I am $stuck\ \\lnx(2x+1)-\int\frac{1}{2x+1}dx$ I u subbed 2x+1 and my 2 canceled out. However, in your answer this is not the case.

Comment: @Sunny. What do you mean the $2$ canceled? If you sub $2x+1=u$ you get $2dx=du$ or $dx=1/2du$ You new integral is of the form $\frac{1}{2}lnudu$ which can be written as $1*lnudu$

Comment: @Sunny I am a little confused by your statement. Have you tried to integrate $\frac{2x}{2x+1}$?

Comment: I got $\int\frac{2}{2x+1}$ How did you get $\int\frac{2x}{2x+1}$

Comment: @Sunny whoops, we're talking on two different answers. Okay integration by parts: $\int u\ dv=uv-\int v\, du$ In our case $u=\ln(2x+1)$ and $v=x$. The integral part is $$\int v\,du=\int x\cdot\frac{2}{2x+1}\,dx=\int\frac{2x}{2x+1}\,dx$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\ln(2x+1)\ \mathrm dx$$
Using integration by parts, we have
$$u=\ln(2x+1)\Rightarrow \mathrm du=\frac{2}{2x+1}\mathrm dx$$
$$\mathrm dv=\mathrm dx\Rightarrow v=x$$
Which yields
$$x\ln(2x+1)-\int\frac{2x}{2x+1}\mathrm dx$$
Using substitution, we have
$$s=2x+1\Rightarrow \frac12\mathrm ds=\mathrm dx$$
Therefore
$$x\ln(2x+1)-\frac12\int\frac{s-1}{s}\mathrm ds$$
$$=x\ln(2x+1)-\frac12\int\left(1-\frac{1}{s}\right)\ \mathrm ds$$
$$=x\ln(2x+1)-\frac12\left(\int\mathrm ds-\int\frac{1}{s}\mathrm ds\right)$$
$$=x\ln(2x+1)-\frac12\int\mathrm ds+\frac12\int\frac{1}{s}\mathrm ds$$
$$=x\ln(2x+1)-\frac12 s+\frac12\ln s+C$$
$$=x\ln(2x+1)-\frac12(2x+1)+\frac12\ln(2x+1)+C$$
$$=\left(x+\frac12\right)\ln(2x+1)-\left(x+\frac12\right)+C$$
$$=\left(x+\frac12\right)\big(\ln(2x+1)-1\big)+C$$

Comment: Your using $s$ twice. I guess I have never seen this. $s=2x+1$ and $s-1=2x$ What does one $call$ what you have done? And when do you $use$ this method?

Comment: Just for confirmation: When you break up an integral$\int f(x)+g(x)=\int f(x)+\int g(x)$ You place the constant on both integrals $\frac{1}{2}\int f(x)+g(x)=$ $\frac{1}{2}\int f(x)+\frac{1}{2}\int g(x)$

Comment: k170 can you answer my questions?

Comment: @Sunny, the method I used is called [integration by substitution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution). And the answer to your last comment is yes.

Comment: I guess this is using u substitution in several or many ways. Ok thanks. How about my second question?

Comment: @Sunny, as far as when to use it? It all depends on the problem. Some problems will only allow you to substitute only once while other problems will allow multiple opportunities.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution by substitution:

$u = 2x + 1$

$x = \frac{u-1}{2}$

$\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{1}{2}$

$\int \log(2x+1) dx = \frac{1}{2}\int \log(u) du = \frac{1}{2}(u \log(u) - u) + C = \frac{1}{2}((2x+1) log(2x+1) - (2x+1)) + C$